# What does product() do in python?

Tags: python

what does product do in python?
How can it be replaced?
what are all it's capabilities.
what does the `*` sign do?
How do you test it without getting the generator warning message thing

```
<itertools.product object at 0x0159BD00>
```

Comment: It's all in the documentation: [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). This is a lazy question that is easily solved by a quick google. It's also multiple questions in one. Go read the SO FAQ and then come back.

Comment: yes, that's where i just came from. i read that before i came here. I understand what it prints out. but i want to understand it better then that

Comment: Read (and work through the examples!!) the official Python tutorial. After the first 5 chapters, you should have a fundamental understanding of the language. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html

Comment: @thebiggerchadder If you truly read the docs and don't understand it, then go learn Python first. The docs give a complete description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It computes the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) over any number of iterables. [Source](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

So if you have two lists like `[1,2]` and `[3,4]`, the Cartesian product is `(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)`

Comment: You really shouldn't dignify questions like this with a response.

Comment: Even bad questions should get answered, that way when people search "[what does product do in python](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+does+product+do+in+python)" and this question is the top hit they don't leave the site thinking that SO sucks.

Comment: Note that by "bad questions" I mean trivial (Google-able) questions, not difficult to understand or "write this code for me" questions.

Comment: thank you flatware, im sure you make the world a better place everyday.

Comment: yea i know what it prints out, but what are the specific mechanics behind it. what is up with the product(*stuff) and product(stuff) what is the difference

Comment: f.j. i googled it and got 20 results for snake food. the only docs i got were the iteritems docs. iteritems docs explain it with complexity. i wasn't able to understand it all so i came here

Comment: @thebiggerchadder The * means that it accepts any number of arguments. If you define a function like `def foo(bar):`, then calling it with more (or less) than one argument will be an error. If you define it as `def foo(*bar):` you can call it with any number of arguments you want (and inside the function, `bar` will be a list containing all the arguments).

Comment: is there a way to mimic the * effect with just loops?

Comment: Ah yes. The old "google it" infinite loop. You tell them to google it, they google it, the search results point them back here telling them to google it. What is the point of SO if the solution is to google it? Nah better yet, don't google. Bing and decide.

Comment: This is a *just google it* answer. The first result on google for `python itertools product` is the docs for `itertools.product()` which explain it's usage in full. If you can't work it out from the (excellent) Python docs, you need to go and learn to program and learn Python before trying to learn specific things like this. There is nothing to say in this answer that isn't repetition of what the docs say - making it unsuitable for SO. It's trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Try iterating over it:

```
for p in itertools.product((1,2,3), (4,5,6)):
    print p
```

produces:

```
(1, 4)
(1, 5)
(1, 6)
(2, 4)
(2, 5)
(2, 6)
(3, 4)
(3, 5)
(3, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the Python [itertools.product docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)? It computes the cartesian product:

> itertools.product(*iterables[, repeat]) Cartesian product of input
>   iterables.
>
> Equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example,
>   product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).

Was there a specific question that you had about this?

Comment: yes i know the basics, but there is more to it.  like the * sign, and the diffidence between with and without it.

Comment: i wanted to know how to do this using just for loops. how to mimic the effect and understand the mechanics of the function.

Comment: @thebiggerchadder Ok, I assume the answers here have give you the information you were looking for. Speaking for myself, there's no better way to learn this sort of thing than to have a Python console open, the reference doc open and google for some examples and then just try different things. Reading about it w/o doing doesn't work too well for me.

Comment: i had my console open, and was trying to use the function without a loop. there i said it. haha